# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python

I have a dictionary "item":

```
>>> item["value"]
Out[2]: u'$26,420'
```

I want to convert this to the integer

```
26420
```

to load into a db. So far I've tried:

```
Out[2]: u'$26,420'
>>> item["value"][1:]
Out[3]: u'26,420'
>>> int(item["value"][1:])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\envs\virtalenvs\teat\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-4-cd6c9e68ae50>", line 1, in <module>
    int(item["value"][1:])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '26,420'
```

Whats the best pythonic way to do this?

Comment: `int(re.sub("[^0-9]","",my_text)`

Comment: is locale setting a concern (commas vs dots, etc)? how about decimals?

Comment: Well I'm glad you asked about decimals. This case does not have them but I wondered about how to deal with them.

Answer (score 5):

Strip away all non-numeric characters:

```
>>> s = '$26,420'
>>> s = ''.join(c for c in s if c.isnumeric())
>>> int(s)
26420
```

Comment: Thanks John is "c for c in s if c.isnumeric()" a comprehension? I want to read up more on this.

Comment: Yes -- it is a comprehension (in the form of a generator-expression rather than a list-comprehension -- note the absence of square brackets). In my opinion such things are what makes Python really shine. A good way to learn them is to read the Python questions on Stack Overflow. Every single day you'll see at least a dozen examples in the answers.

Answer (score 2):

```
some_amount = "$12,345"
some_amount = int(some_amount.split("$")[1].replace(",", ""))
print some_amount #Will return 12345 as an int
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: No problem! Anytime!

Answer (score 2):

You could chain two simple replaces together:

```
cur = int(cur.replace("$", "").replace(",", ""))
```

Comment: Thank you very much